# how to ideavim combine two action

Tags: vim, ideavim

Hi I'm try to customize my ~/_ideavim like this

```
nmap za :action ReformatCode<CR>
nmap zb :action RiderUnitTestRunSolutionAction<CR>
nmap zc :action ReformatCode<CR>:action RiderUnitTestRunSolutionAction<CR>
```

when I try press `za` and `zb` it work very well
it can be format my Code Or run the unit tests

But when I try to combine two action like `zc`
it just work last action .

If it possible Run Test after Reformat  ?

Comment: Where can I find list of Rider commands?

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple commands at once with the `|`

```
nmap zc :action ReformatCode  \| action RiderUnitTestRunSolutionAction<CR>
```

Comment: it not work for me , I am use Rider on Macbook . 
still only one action be excuted

Comment: Sorry there also was a typo in it. try again.

Comment: Don’t you need to escape that bar in the mapping?

Comment: still not work 
`nmap zc :action ReformatCode | action RiderUnitTestRunSolutionAction<CR>`

Comment: your mean is escape `|` ?

Comment: Head => Table. You are absolutely right @D.BenKnoble. Sorry Marsen, please see the updated solution