# ideavim how to combine an action with a vim command

Tags: webstorm, ideavim

i'd like to do something like this

```
nnoremap m[ :action MethodUp<cr> + zz
```

to move up a function but also keep it centered, is that possible?

I've tried the solution from [how to ideavim combine two action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760660/how-to-ideavim-combine-two-action) like so but it doesn't work

```
nmap zc :action  MethodUp<cr>  \| zz
```

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is more of a question about intellij i think than vim